# Two domain names for one website

Tags: web, domain-name

I have 1 hosting account with Fatcow which has 2 domain names (i.e: website1.com and website2.com). It works perfectly, except when I enter website2.com, it changes to website1.com in the address bar. Is it possible to have website2.com remain in the address bar (only if website2.com is entered, and vice versa).

Thank you for your time.

Comment: is website2.com a subdomain?

Comment: @AGrammerPro no subdomains

Comment: you should be able to have two domains(Which I would not recommend). Are you sure you don't have website2.com doing some type of redirect to website1.com?

Comment: I've looked into it but I can't find anything regarding redirecting. Maybe I should contact my web host.